# UIView changes not reflecting in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am building an iOS app in iOS 6 and iOS 7. The problem i am facing with is i am changing my uiview programmatically. But the changes are reflected in iOS 6 and not in iOS 7. What to do ? For Example, I change my iutableview height, the height changes in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7.

```
tableCellHeight = 44;
    tableX = 0;
    tableY = 118;
    tableWidth = 320;
    tableHeight = tableCellHeight * 2;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableX, tableY, tableWidth, tableHeight);
```

Comment: Question not complete. Can you post some code what you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

One has to put the resizing into -viewDidLayoutSubviews:! -viewWillAppear: and -viewDidLoad: doesn't work, because the views are not laying out yet!